# Laravel : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

when I make a php artisan migrate I receive this error:

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

However I am well connected to the database because I already have model for tables already present in this database.

Comment: You may be connecting to the wrong port or wrong host name in your migration. This is something you need to figure out because based on the error message, your connection details are simply not correct.

Comment: but in this case, why should I use certain models?

Comment: are your database settings correct in your env file?

Comment: Those models probably have different mysql connection properties. We can only guess because apart from the error message, there is nothing else in your question.

Comment: yes, unfortunately this is the only error message I get.

Comment: You must look at your config files that contain the connection strings. Modify your migration files to print out the mysql connection string details. Try something!

Comment: my config is file is correct

Comment: Problem solved, I use Vagrant and a shared folder between my office and Vagrant. I had to start the migration from Vagrant SSH and not from my local.